# Solve For The Word (3)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, word

Here is the puzzle :

---

```
57  1  0  72          A

45  6  3  54

33 12  6  36

R   L  I   Z          D

I = A

D = L
```

---

Hints:

Hint (1):

> The order of the missing numbers represents a reptile name.

Hint (2):

> Q = 17

Comment: You can use code formatting (four spaces before each line) to use a monospace font if alignment matters

Comment: Yeah sorry about this @StephenS

Comment: I've fixed the formatting. Roll back the edit if it's broken anything puzzle related...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from [avenger12's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53699/39491)

Summary of known information:

> Solving for the numeric values of the letters by following the pattern of the columns:
>  57, 45, 33, (R=21)
>  1, 6, 12, (L=19)
>  0, 3, 6, (I=9)
>  72, 54, 36, (Z=18)
>  Given that I=A and D=L, we have:
>  R = 21
>  L = D = 19
>  I = A = 9
>  Z = 18

Given the first hint, these numbers should be arranged in the order that they appear in the reptile name:

> L I Z A R D
>  19 9 18 9 21 19

Given the second hint:

> Each resulting number corresponds to the letter at the same position in the alphabet. (Q is the 17th letter of the alphabet)
>  19 → S
>  9 → I
>  18 → R
>  21 → U

Therefore, the hidden word is:

> SIRIUS

Answer (score 3):

Rookie attempt, I'm not sure it looks this easy, but here goes nothing.

The reptile word is:

> Lizard so I assume to solve for missing numbers in that order.

Solving for L:

> We start of with 1, then 6, then 12, so the pattern I recognize is that 6-1 = 5 and 12-6 = 6. Thus my best guess is that the difference between 12 and the next number will be 7 so L = D = 19.

Solving for I:

> Each number in this column is incremented by 3. Thus, I = A = 9

Solving for Z:

> Each number in the column decreases by 18 so Z = 18.

Solving for R:

> Each number in the column decreases by 12 so R = 21.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that you are on the right track